# Spring + Hibernate randomly freezes after hours

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am working on a web application with springMVC+spring+hibernate and deployed it with Tomcat 8.0.36 and proxying pass it with *nginx* to port 80. It runs normally at the beginning, but after a few hours (normally from 10 to 20) it freezes and cannot process any requests.

To demonstrate the reason i checked several logs around and during the down time.

- In the access log of *ngnix*, the incoming requests are logged, with http status 504 or 499.
- In the access log of *tomcat*, no requests are logged during the downtime and the requests around that time are all successfully processed (having status 200)
- In the *catalina.out* (log4j set to debug level), there was no ERROR logged. And there  I could see that the application itself seems to be alive during the down time since there is an `IdleConnectionHandler` keeping logging things like:

> 09:41:33,246 DEBUG IdleConnectionHandler:108 - Checking for connections, idleTimeout: 1474076493216

I found that the problem may be around the hibernate getting the JDBC connection and begin the transaction after further experiment and logging.

After the server freezes, requests without using the database will be logged as successfully completed in *catalina.out* but not logged in the tomcats' access log. And in the ngnix's log it failed with status 504.（**UPDATE**: From the log i    found that theses requests are also trying to begin a transaction after `successfully completed` logged by `DispatcherServlet`. I don't know why. Maybe has something to do with Spring event listener.)

On the other hand, for requests that will access the database via hibernate, their threads will end up with a `preparing JDBC connection` Like this:

```
23:38:17,211 DEBUG [THREAD ID=http-nio-8080-exec-156] DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'queryServiceImpl'
23:38:17,211 DEBUG [THREAD ID=http-nio-8080-exec-156] HibernateTransactionManager:380 - Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6059c46 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4671f5ca deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2d02684b orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3815fcf9 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@12d8a011 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5b4ec825 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6530a337 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72d5795c unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
23:38:17,211 DEBUG [THREAD ID=http-nio-8080-exec-156] HibernateTransactionManager:367 - Creating new transaction with name [com.pia.mainWeb.service.impl.QueryServiceImpl.get]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
23:38:17,212 DEBUG [THREAD ID=http-nio-8080-exec-156] HibernateTransactionManager:445 - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6059c46 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4671f5ca deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@2d02684b orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3815fcf9 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@12d8a011 collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@5b4ec825 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@6530a337 collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@72d5795c unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
```

If I compare it with what should be printed when the server is running properly, 
the next line should be a `transaction begin`:

```
23:37:52,966 DEBUG [THREAD ID=http-nio-8080-exec-52] TransactionImpl:51 - begin
```

Then I referred to the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager` Class and found the place where things could went wrong (around line 442 to line 500):

```
if (this.prepareConnection && isSameConnectionForEntireSession(session)) {
                // We're allowed to change the transaction settings of the JDBC Connection.
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [" + session + "]");
                }
                Connection con = ((SessionImplementor) session).connection();
                Integer previousIsolationLevel = DataSourceUtils.prepareConnectionForTransaction(con, definition);
                txObject.setPreviousIsolationLevel(previousIsolationLevel);
                if (this.allowResultAccessAfterCompletion && !txObject.isNewSession()) {
                    int currentHoldability = con.getHoldability();
                    if (currentHoldability != ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT) {
                        txObject.setPreviousHoldability(currentHoldability);
                        con.setHoldability(ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Not allowed to change the transaction settings of the JDBC Connection.
                if (definition.getIsolationLevel() != TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT) {
                    // We should set a specific isolation level but are not allowed to...
                    throw new InvalidIsolationLevelException(
                            "HibernateTransactionManager is not allowed to support custom isolation levels: " +
                            "make sure that its 'prepareConnection' flag is on (the default) and that the " +
                            "Hibernate connection release mode is set to 'on_close' (the default for JDBC).");
                }
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Not preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [" + session + "]");
                }
            }

            if (definition.isReadOnly() && txObject.isNewSession()) {
                // Just set to MANUAL in case of a new Session for this transaction.
                session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
            }

            if (!definition.isReadOnly() && !txObject.isNewSession()) {
                // We need AUTO or COMMIT for a non-read-only transaction.
                FlushMode flushMode = session.getFlushMode();
                if (session.getFlushMode().equals(FlushMode.MANUAL)) {
                    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
                    txObject.getSessionHolder().setPreviousFlushMode(flushMode);
                }
            }

            Transaction hibTx;

            // Register transaction timeout.
            int timeout = determineTimeout(definition);
            if (timeout != TransactionDefinition.TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) {
                // Use Hibernate's own transaction timeout mechanism on Hibernate 3.1+
                // Applies to all statements, also to inserts, updates and deletes!
                hibTx = session.getTransaction();
                hibTx.setTimeout(timeout);
                hibTx.begin(); // <---- Will print "begin" here
            }
            else {
                // Open a plain Hibernate transaction without specified timeout.
                hibTx = session.beginTransaction(); // <---- Will print "begin" here
            }
```

However i still could not figure out what is going wrong. The crash seems randomly and I could not find a way to reproduce it in a test environment. The versions of my server dependencies are:

- Spring and Spring-mvc 4.2.3.RELEASE
- Hibernate 5.0.2.Final

It looks to me that these threads are somehow blocked by something. Could it be a deadlock somewhere in the transaction? I did not set the transaction timeout  for now (left it -1 as default) and I am not sure if this will cause a deadlock between threads.

Anyone please help me with this. Any idea or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

I tried to dump threads when the server hung. And the problem is maybe just like what is described by @ike3. All the threads are waiting to get connections from `org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource`.

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-132" #6824 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56c4067000 nid=0x1f40 in Object.wait() [0x00007f56a6981000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1126)
    - locked <0x000000069b573e18> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:488)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:447)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy184.onApplicationEvent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor138.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.onApplicationEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.controller.VetController.onApplicationEvent(VetController.java:1327)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.controller.VetController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bb2aa9d5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.controller.VetController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdc9f985.onApplicationEvent(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.publishRequestHandledEvent(FrameworkServlet.java:1073)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.filter.UrlSessionFilter.doFilter(UrlSessionFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.filter.ReferralFilter.doFilter(ReferralFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.pia.mainWeb.filter.DomainFilter.doFilter(DomainFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    - locked <0x00000007639923d0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However i am still not sure about the solution. Now I changed the dataSource Implementation to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` with `testWhileIdle` set to true and `SELECT 1` to validate the query. The effect still needs further check tho.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mvcdb.mysql.driver}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1"/>
        <property name="validationInterval" value="10000"/>
        <property name="url" value="${mvcdb.mysql.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${mvcdb.mysql.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${mvcdb.mysql.password}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${mvcdb.mysql.initialSize}"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="${mvcdb.mysql.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${mvcdb.mysql.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${mvcdb.mysql.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="${mvcdb.mysql.maxWait}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="120"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Have you enabled DEBUG level logging on some spring core classes?  (e.g., `org.springframework.web` `org.spring.web.context` `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`) Sometimes it'll give you more information

Comment: I have set `log4j.rootLogger`'s level to DEBUG and there is no specific properties set for child loggers so i think i already have the messages. Is that right?

Comment: Which database do you use? I had once a very similar issue with MySQL and fixed it by adding validate query `SELECT 1` to the connection pool settings.

Comment: Is this is not a full garbage collecting trouble ? Try to add ``-XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`` to the command line to check for full GC occurence and duration.

Comment: @ike3 Yes i am using MySQL too. Could u explain more about how you solved this problem? That may be very useful for me.

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis Thx for your reply. I will try check it but i don't think it has something to do with GC. Once it hangs it will not come back anymore.(I waited for 20 minutes but it seems could not come back by itself.. then I have to restart it since it is in production environment.)  And neither the memory nor CPU was very high when this happened.

Comment: In my case idle connections were not marked as inactive and remain active so the app received them from pool. Any operation under that connection hung. Making the connection validated before using marked it as inactive properly. Unfortunately most idle connections were OK, so the issue was rarely reproduced.

Comment: Yes, they should inherit from parent loggers if configured correctly.  As for the SELECT 1 item, for Hikari CP, you can do `config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1")`; for java config.  XML config is similar.  You can google around if you use another connection pool.  And on that topic, if you're really stumped, you can try switching to a different connection pool provider.  I've seen some issues go away by doing so.

Comment: @ike3 , bphilipnyc Thank you for your guys. It did turn out to be something with the dataSource connection pool. See my updated question.

Comment: @MMhunter Could you give me clues how exactly did you deal with your problem ? I have the same problem in spring+mybatis. How to dump threads ?

Comment: @user8820082 Hi, it was a long time ago and i am no longer working on this project, so i cannot remember every detail. Maybe just as i said in the post, i changed the datasource implementation and some configuration. It looks like to me Now that maybe this problem is that the dead connections are not released somehow. The new implementation handles the issue better. Not sure tho. The tool to dump threads was an official tool call [jstack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html).